# Why is that additional entity classes created for one to many/ many to many relationships when generating persistence mapping in Intellij idea?

Tags: intellij-idea, spring-data-jpa

When using "generate persistence mapping" in intellij idea, I got several additional entity classes for one to many and many to many relationships.

There's a table for many to many relationships and it has two keys for the tables. Entity class generated for that and another class generated for the same attributes with serializable.

Why is that?

Comment: Sounds like https://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issue/IDEA-178353

Answer (score 0):

check whether you checked table relationship options in generate persistence mapping to get codes generate for @ManytoOne @OnetoMany relationships.